# How to define different messages when Navigation Away and Reloading page?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I want a simple thing, but I am not getting it to work

Just like the browser change the confirmation text from

> "Are you sure you want to leave this page?"

to

> "Are you sure you want to reload this page?"

depending what you are doing, I want that my custom confirmation text also knows which action the user is performing.

Currently I have this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var infoText = (event.srcElement == event.target) ? "Reloading" : "Movig from";
    infoText += " this page will cause you to lose current information.";
    return infoText;
};
```

I thought that comparing the `event.srcElement` vs. `event.target` will be enough as they have the navigation links. But that `if` statement always returns `true`, so it always looks like it is reloading even if the destination link is different.

As the browser knows, I thinks there must be some way to do it. If not, I'll have to create a generic message.
(Obviously I could make it generic and... done. But now I really want to know it.)

Comment: i dont think your code can know that.

Comment: By "your" you mean what I have or what I could have? The former I agree, as stated on the question...

Comment: The thing that bugs me is why the `URL` inside `event.target` does not change when I move to a different page. If I not getting its purpose wrong, it should to me...

Comment: a pretty dirty attemp would be a keydown eventlistener on the whole dom that checks for the f5 key. You could utilize this example http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/C85Hs/